# Local Notification For IOS Using Cordova

Tags: ios, git, cordova

I try to download plugin in terminal using command
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

my os:MAC OS 10.8.5 and xcode 4.3

before download BUILD SUCCEEDED

but after download plugin I get error

```
error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c git clone "https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications" 
"/var/folders/s0/x_bcn18d51zd33vx03tltwm40000gn/T/git/1433249592654"
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

so , I need to help to solve this problem

Comment: Have you added your cordova plugin?
if not then add like `$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications build ios`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing the XCode Comman-Line Tools. To install them:

1. Open XCode and hit `CMD` + `,`
2. Click Downloads
3. Install the Command-Line Tools.

Rerun your command - it should work then.

---

> my os:MAC OS 10.8.5 and xcode **4.3**

for real? 4.3 must be from 2012 or earlier...